# Join in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entites

**Course**

```
public class Course{

    int courseId;

    int courseName;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.Lazy,mappedBy="course")
    Set <CourseProperty> courseProp;

    ... setters & getters
}
```

**Course property**

```
public class CourseProperty{

    int courseId;
    int prop1;
    int prop2;
    int prop3;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.lazy)
    @JoinColumn(name="courseId",referencedColumnName="courseId",insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @JsonIgnore
    Course course;

    ... setters & getters

}
```

Now this is the bi-directional join. So I have to place `@JsonIgnore` in the `Course` attribute of `CourseProp` otherwise when I print the `course` object, it results in infinite loop.

But Now I can't print Course Prop Object with Course Object in it. How do I change my entities. Let Say i want to do query something like

```
Select * from Course a join CourseProp b on a.courseId = b.courseId and b.prop1="demo"
```

I want to run this query(by Spring Data JPA) from CourseProp repository which will result CourseProp Object but becoz of JsonIgnore, I wont get Course Object inside Course Prop.

Comment: Could you give more information about your project? Why do you use @JsonIgnore annotation?

Comment: Becoz If I want to print an persisted object of COurse(fetched using findOne), then it is sort of infinite loop, as Course Object has Course Prop inside it & Course Prop has Course Object inside it. So it keeps on going nested like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a good idea to directly serialize your `Entities` to `JSON` with frameworks like `Jackson`. Because these frameworks try to completely serialize your passing objects to `JSON` and because your `Entities` are `Hibernate` Proxies, it will fetch all the associations of your objects. even those properties that you marked as `LAZY` and you didn't need them. Also if you have bidirectional relationships in your objects, you will trap in an infinite loop.

Instead, i think it's better to create `Model` or `DTO` classes for your `Entities` and instantiate them with the properties that you need and then serialize those objects to `JSON`.